# How to make NSURL with special characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

My application is based in Portuguese - Brazil. We have some special characters that we use in words like "Açaí".

I have a search method that sends a request to a URL like this:

```
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mydomain.com.br/webservice/search/%@",_query];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:URL
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {
   //ALL THE LOGIC HERE
                });

            }] resume];
```

Now, if the _query is set "Açaí" (which has ç and í as special characters) when I try `NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];` the URL variable is not initialized and breaks all the rest.

How can I send a request to my web service using special characters?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape the url string before creating the `NSURL`.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mydomain.com.br/webservice/search/%@",_query];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```